R swimmer plot: 4 legends and layers issues
I am having an issue with my swimmer plot legends. I want four layers and legends 1) medical treatment 2) response 3) AE and 4) procedure. I can't get more than three and I think it is an issue related to using scale_color_manual for both medical treatment and procedure. How can I avoid this? I can post a bit of data, but wondering if anyone could help me just by looking at these legend codes!
library(swimplot) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr)

#swimmer plot code with gap data 
swimp <- swimmer_plot(df = swimn, id = 'study_id', start = "ther_start", end = "ther_end", name_fill = "ther_type",  color = NA,   id_order = sort(unique(swimn$study_id), decreasing = TRUE) ) + theme_bw(base_size = 20) +   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +   coord_flip(clip = 'off', expand = FALSE) +   scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))

#fix axes and legend 
swimp <- swimp +  scale_x_discrete(name="Study ID") +
     scale_y_continuous(name="Time since Therapy Initiation (yr)", breaks=seq(-10,10,by=1))+
     scale_fill_manual(name="Medical Treatment",values=cols, labels=names(cols), breaks=names(cols), na.value="gray78")  
     #not showing NA values in legend label

#add arrows if continued treatment 
swimp <- swimp + swimmer_arrows(df_arrows=swimn, id="study_id",arrow_start="ther_end", cont="continued_tx", name_col="simple_resp",type="open",cex=0.5,linewidth=2, show.legend=FALSE, arrow_positions=c(0,0.5)) + scale_color_discrete(drop=FALSE)

#add responses 
swimp <- swimp + swimmer_lines(df_lines=swimn,id="study_id",start="ther_start",end="ther_end", name_col="simple_resp",size=2) + scale_color_manual(name="Response", values=c("PD"="red","SD"="grey49","PR"="orange","CR"="chartreuse3"), breaks=c("PD","SD","PR","CR"),labels=c("Progressive Disease","Stable Disease", "Partial Response","Complete Response")) 

# Add points for adverse events 
swimp <- swimp +    swimmer_points(
    df_points = swimn[!is.na(swimn$discont_ae), ],  id = "study_id", time = "ther_end", 
    name_shape="discont_ae", size = 4, fill = "black", col = "black") +    scale_shape_manual(
    name = "Adverse Event", values = c(AE = 22, SAE = 21, Death = 24), breaks = c("AE", "SAE", "Death"))

#colors for different procedure combinations 
cols_sclero <- c("Surgical"='deeppink3', "Interventional"='forestgreen')

#add points for different interventions 
swimp <- swimp +    swimmer_points(df_points = as.data.frame(sclero),  id = "study_id",  time = "procedure_time",  size = 4,   shape = 16,  name_col = "procedure_category") +    scale_color_manual(name = "Treatment Category", values = cols_sclero,  breaks = names(cols_sclero), labels = names(cols_sclero))

#combining legends 
swimp <- swimp + guides( color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)), fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=NA)), shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(color=NA)))


If the problem is multiple scales of color/fill, you may be able to use the package ggnewscale to find a solution. However, if you want a dedicated answer to your specific question and you want it quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from dput() or reprex::reprex(). Check it out: making R reproducible questions.
